# Divs not aligning with each other in a UL - LI

Tags: html, css

I want to have 4 boxes with weather info in them. I am happy with everything, but the tops of the boxes are at different spots. How I do make them line up at the top? Total beginner. I am not sure if this is even the best way to go about achieving what I want.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 3em;
}

div {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  position: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>City Name</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h1>Current</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>12oC</h2>
      <h3>Feels: 9oC</h3>
      <h3>Mostly Sunny</h3>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Today</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>15oC Hi</h2>
      <h3>Mostly Sunny</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Tonight</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>-63oC Lo</h2>
      <h3>Mostly Cloudy</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Details</h1>
      <img id="flag" src="./flags/by.png">
      <h3>Wind CHill: -5oC</h3>
      <h3>Sunrise: 05:00</h3>
      <h3>Sunset: 16:00</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;  vertical-align: top;` Although if you are looking for a better approach use flexbox or grid

Comment: Thanks you, I will look into flexbox and grid

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@j08691's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709366/#answer-60709542), you should consider using more semantic and accessible markup. Instead of a list, with `<div>` elements and lots of heading elements, consider using [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article), [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section), and [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) elements with the appropriate headings:

```css
section {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  position: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
  color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
dt:after {
  content: ':';
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>City Name</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Current</h2>
    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
    <dl>
      <dt>Temperature</dt>
      <dd>12ºC</dd>
      <dt>Feels</dt>
      <dd>9ºC</dd>
      <dt>Conditions</dt>
      <dd>Mostly Sunny</dd>
    </dl>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Today</h2>
    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
    <dl>
      <dt>High</dt>
      <dd>15ºC</dd>
      <dt>Conditions</dt>
      <dd>Mostly Sunny</dd>
    </dl>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Tonight</h2>
    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
    <dl>
      <dt>Low</dt>
      <dd>-63ºC</dd>
      <dt>Conditions</dt>
      <dd>Mostly Cloudy</dd>
    </dl>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <img id="flag" src="./flags/by.png">
    <dl>
      <dt>Wind Chill</dt>
      <dd>-5ºC</dd>
      <dt>Sunrise</dt>
      <dd>05:00</dd>
      <dt>Sunset</dt>
      <dd>16:00</dd>
    </dl>
  </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default vertical alignment for inline elements in `baseline`. Change it to top (or something other than baseline) and they line up:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 3em;
}

div {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  position: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
  color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<h1>City Name</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h1>Current</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>12oC</h2>
      <h3>Feels: 9oC</h3>
      <h3>Mostly Sunny</h3>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Today</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>15oC Hi</h2>
      <h3>Mostly Sunny</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Tonight</h1>
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
      <h2>-63oC Lo</h2>
      <h3>Mostly Cloudy</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Details</h1>
      <img id="flag" src="./flags/by.png">
      <h3>Wind CHill: -5oC</h3>
      <h3>Sunrise: 05:00</h3>
      <h3>Sunset: 16:00</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```